Dynamic URL/Routing In Python Dash
I'm creating a dash app that has the following structure.
app.py
│── pages
│ ├── table.py
│ ├── company.py
│ ├── ...

A few additional details that might be relevant:

The table is generated dynamically within a callback.
It already incorporates pagination to limit the number of rows displayed.
There are sorting options available for certain columns.
The table is built using html.Table

One of the columns in the table is a name, which I would like to function as a dynamic URL/button that redirects to a new company-specific page with visualizations. Is that possible without creating the company specific pages as actual .py files?
Everything I've read about multi-page dash apps, requires .py files to function
